# Javascript Object - Map through object and filter value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, mapping

Currently, I am able to retrieve list of shows provided by Netflix.

However my score filter is not returning what I want.
I want to return a list with tmdb:score of 8 or greater. 
Since the data structure (stored in the `searchResult` variable) is splitting provider_type and value, I am getting any score 8 or greater at the moment.

Is there a way to do this? 
If possible, combine it with my Netflix provider function to return Netflix shows with tmdb:score of 8 or greater?

Thank you.

Node JS File

```
const JustWatch = require("justwatch-api")
const netflixId = 8;

function print_result (name, result) {
    console.log(name+":");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    console.log("\n\n\n\n");
}

(async function(){
    var justwatch = new JustWatch();

    var searchResult = await justwatch.search('a');

    searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
         movie.offers.forEach(offer => {
             if(offer.provider_id === netflixId){
                 print_result("search", searchResult)
             }
         })
     })


    searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
        movie.scoring.filter(score =>{
            if(score.provider_type ==="tmdb:score" && score.value > 8) {
                print_result("search", searchResult)
            }
        })
    })

}) ();
```

Data structure (as stored in the `searchResult` variable, an object containing a count `total_results` and an array `items` of objects, each representing a movie)

```
{
    "total_results": 27476,
    "items": [
        {
            "jw_entity_id": "ts80908",
            "id": 80908,
            "title": "A Very English Scandal",
            "full_path": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal",
            "full_paths": {
                "SHOW_DETAIL_OVERVIEW": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal"
            },
            "poster": "/poster/60368458/{profile}",
            "original_release_year": 2018,
            "tmdb_popularity": 3.422,
            "object_type": "show",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 8.1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "jw_entity_id": "tm205151",
            "id": 205151,
            "title": "Alpha",
            "full_path": "/us/movie/alpha-2015",
            "full_paths": {
                "MOVIE_DETAIL_OVERVIEW": "/us/movie/alpha-2015"
            },
....
```

Comment: So, "Data structure" in your question refers to the value in `searchResult`, which returns an object with a count in `total_results` and an array of objects `items`, each of which represents a movie, correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Isn't `justwatch.search('a');` supposed to be `justwatch.search({query:yourQueryString});`? You have the search as a String. That's not what the docs show.

Comment: @StackSlave yes I changed it but I believe it was returning same thing as {query: 'a'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a filtered array of movie objects with tmdb:score>=8.0, here's a snippet to demonstrate (Note that I've mocked an object in the same format as yours with an `items` array of just two almost identical objects, one with the score>8.0 and one with the score<8.0 for the purpose of demonstration):

```js
const searchResult = {
    "total_results": 27476,
    "items": [
        {
            "jw_entity_id": "ts80908",
            "id": 80908,
            "title": "A Very English Scandal",
            "full_path": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal",
            "full_paths": {
                "SHOW_DETAIL_OVERVIEW": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal"
            },
            "poster": "/poster/60368458/{profile}",
            "original_release_year": 2018,
            "tmdb_popularity": 3.422,
            "object_type": "show",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 8.1
                }
            ]
        },{
            "jw_entity_id": "ts80909",
            "id": 80908,
            "title": "Some Other Title",
            "full_path": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal",
            "full_paths": {
                "SHOW_DETAIL_OVERVIEW": "/us/tv-show/a-very-english-scandal"
            },
            "poster": "/poster/60368458/{profile}",
            "original_release_year": 2018,
            "tmdb_popularity": 3.422,
            "object_type": "show",
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 7.9
                }
            ]
        }]
 }

 const desiredMovies = searchResult.items.filter(movie => {
  let tmdbScoring = movie.scoring.find(scoringObj => scoringObj.provider_type==="tmdb:score");
  return tmdbScoring && tmdbScoring.value>=8.0;
 })

 console.log(desiredMovies);
```

Also, I've noticed what seems to be an issue in the code that you've added, which might explain why you're getting all the movies.

In the code below, you're printing `searchResult` once for every successful result you're finding, which is an object which contains the count and the entire array `items`, so that'll show you all the movies in your data structure.

```
//searchResult is the object that contains the entire array "items"
searchResult.items.map(function(movie){
    movie.scoring.filter(score =>{
        if(score.provider_type ==="tmdb:score" && score.value > 8) {
            //the variable searchResult has scope here so it will contain the entire list
            print_result("search", searchResult)
        }
    })
})
```

**Disclaimer**: The following is meant only as constructive criticism.

Also, I'm fairly certain your usage of `.map` and `.filter` is incorrect. The callbacks supplied to these need to return a boolean value so that the `.map` or `.filter` functions themselves can return a new array (important to note that `.map` and `.filter` do not affect the original array). Not only do the callbacks supplied not return a boolean, the results of the map or filter themselves are not being stored in a variable. So, I suggest you take a look at the docs for these higher-order functions to get a better understanding of how they work:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Therefore I suggest you make a function that returns the filtered list of movies from the `items` list of your object and print that altogether.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your code works perfectly. I wanted to combine with my provider finding function.
```
  const desiredMovies = searchResult.items.filter(movie => {
        let tmdbScoring = movie.scoring.find(scoringObj => scoringObj.provider_type === "tmdb:score");
        let netflixproviding = movie.offers.find(offer => offer.provider_id === netflixId);
        return netflixproviding && tmdbScoring && tmdbScoring.value >= 8;
    })
    print_result("search", desiredMovies)
```
Doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Let's translate the problem statement into javascript first. To be clear, you want an array of movies in `desiredMovies` such that for each movie object, there exists an object in `offers` array with `provider_id` 8 **and** an object in `scoring` array with `provider_type` "tmdb:score" and `value` greater than/equal to 8. (It always helps to state the problem clearly)

Comment: `const desiredMovies = searchResult.items.filter(movie => { let tmdbScoring = movie.scoring.find(scoringObj => scoringObj.provider_type === "tmdb:score"); let netflixproviding = movie.offers.find(offer => offer.provider_id === netflixId); return netflixproviding && tmdbScoring && tmdbScoring.value >= 8; }) print_result("search", desiredMovies) ` works as well. Check your sample searchResult, make sure it has provider_id : 8 in it.

Comment: @Colin yeah, my mocked `items` list does not have any `provider_id` equal to 8, changed it to 8, and works.

Comment: thank you I changed to tmdb score >=7 and returned result. I assumed there would be at least one show with rating greater than 8 because of data length.
Thank you again for your detailed response. Will definitely look into understanding higher order functions.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to filter Netflix shows with tmdb:score of 8 or greater right? So can we just use `filter` to filter the items?

```
searchResult.items.filter(function(movie){
    var scorings = movie.scoring;
    var filterScores = 
        scorings.filter(score => score.provider_type ==="tmdb:score" && score.value > 8);
    return filterScores.length > 0;
})
```

Comment: this returns tmdb:popularity > 8 as well

Comment: Do you want to add a condition offer.provider_id === netflixId combining with this? Or what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const netflixId = 8

const searchResult = {
    "items": [
        {
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 8,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 8.1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "offers": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 8,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "sd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                },
                {
                    "type": "aggregated",
                    "monetization_type": "flatrate",
                    "provider_id": 9,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "subtitle_languages": [
                        "en"
                    ],
                    "presentation_type": "hd",
                    "element_count": 1,
                    "new_element_count": 1,
                    "date_provider_id": "2019-09-14_9",
                    "date_created": "2019-09-14"
                }
            ],
            "scoring": [
                {
                    "provider_type": "imdb:score",
                    "value": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:popularity",
                    "value": 3.422
                },
                {
                    "provider_type": "tmdb:score",
                    "value": 7.9
                }
            ]
        }
]}
        
        
const movies = searchResult.items.filter(item => {
  return item.offers.some(offer => offer.provider_id === netflixId) && item.scoring.some(score => score.provider_type === 'tmdb:score'&&score.value>=8)
})

console.log(movies)
```

```
const movies = searchResult.items.filter(item => {
  return item.offers.some(offer => offer.provider_id === netflixId) && item.scoring.some(score => score.provider_type === 'tmdb:score'&&score.value>=8)
})
```

This filter function filter out item based on 2 conditions.

1. In item offers, one of offer needs to be from netflix
2. In item scoring, one of score needs to be tmdb:score and the score needs to be greater or equal than 8.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I look at 'some' function. Seems cool!
However, it is returning []

Comment: you need to console log out or print out movies.

Comment: const movies = searchResult.items.filter(item => {
        return item.offers.some(offer => offer.provider_id === netflixId) && item.scoring.some(score => score.provider_type === 'tmdb:score'&&score.value>=8)

      })
    print_result('search',movies)


returning search: []

Comment: If you run the code snippet, you will see the result is not empty. If it returns empty from your search result, then maybe there is no such movie from netflix with tmdb score >=8